# Getting FileNotFound error on Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, file-read

I am trying to get data from a file using:

```
fileName = 'file_xyz'
f = open(fileName,'r')
```

on Google Colab.

However I keep getting file not found error.

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file_xyz'

I made sure the code and the file are on the same directory. I do not know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Colab sets the working directory to `/content`. You can move your file there and use your code or, alternatively, open the file via its absolute path.

Comment: I thought I was using the files own path when calling it, locating it on the files menu and copying the path from there solved my issue. thanks!